# creating text in webpage like in the gif below

Tags: javascript, text

i want to create a text in a webpage like a timer goes out using js like in the gif image[image: image here]

my code is given below .. it show text like 12345678910...

```js
var i;
for (i=0 ; i < 10; i++) 
{
document.write(i);
}
```

Comment: You should try to design how your requirements can be implemented and then implement it technically.
Try to think about what elements are needed and what has to happen to get the desired result.
Then you could try to research in the documentation which methods could help you to implement it.

hint: compare document.write and element.innerHTML

https://devdocs.io/dom/document/write
https://devdocs.io/dom/element/innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you want to use

`document.body = i`

but the best idea would be to make a text element and then put your text into that element --

In your HTML:
`<p id="foo"></p>`

then in your JS:

`var element = document.getElementById("foo");
element.innerHTML = i`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand loops in JavaScript. Loops are done immediately and not one loop per second. You need to have some timing. You could use `window.setTimeout` or `window.setInterval`, but I prefer `requestAnimationFrame` along with some `Date()` calculation like here

```js
console.clear();
function startTimer(element, seconds) {
  "use strict";

  var start = new Date();
  var now, diff, eta;
  
  function getMinutes() {
    return Math.max(0, Math.ceil((eta - eta % 60) / 60))
  }
  function getSeconds() {
    return Math.max(0, Math.ceil(eta % 60))
  }
  function format(x) {
    return (''+x).padStart(2, '0');
  }
  function draw() {
    element.innerHTML = format(getMinutes()) + ':' + format(getSeconds())
  }
  function finished() {
    element.classList.add('finished')
  }
  
  function update() {
    now = new Date();
    
    diff = (now.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000
    eta = seconds - diff;
    draw()    
    
    if (eta > 0) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
    } else {
      finished()
    }
  }
  update()
}

startTimer(document.getElementById("timer"), 720);
```

```css
#timer {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#timer.finished {
  color: red;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```